# playn-showcase-html is not a GWT project

Tags: eclipse, gwt, playn

As per the [getting started wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/playn/wiki/GettingStarted), I had Indigo with the Android plugin installed; I installed the `Maven Integration for WTP` and `Google` plugins (in that order). I can run the Java version of the showcase fine; when I try to `Google` > `GWT Compile` the showcase-html, Eclipse tells me that this is "not a GWT project."

What am I doing wrong? Or is this broken?

Source can be found here for the next seven days: http://www.sendspace.com/file/zc2af3

Comment: If you have the WTP and Google plugins installed, it should auto-detect the GWT nature of the playn-showcase-html project.

What version of those plugins do you have installed? Perhaps they are not the latest versions. The Google plugin only acquired the ability to autodetect GWT projects in its most recent update.

Comment: @samskivert I have the latest versions installed as of today -- I just installed everything about an hour before asking my question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With all of those plugins installed Eclipse should auto-detect the GWT "nature" of the yourgame-html subproject. It works fine for me and at least a few other people.

In any case, you can simply right click on that project, select "Google -> Web Toolkit Settings..." and click "Use Google Web Toolkit" on the dialog that pops up.

Comment: Thanks, this was actually the solution. Do I have to do this every time I want to compile the HTML5 version? It took ~45 seconds the first time, ~20 seconds the second time.

Comment: You only need to check "Use Google Web Toolkit" once, and it should remember that setting. However, you do need to select "GWT Compile" every time you want to test the HTML5 version of your game, and it does take in the neighborhood of 30 seconds to compile the game to JavaScript. I strongly recommend testing your game using the Java backend, and only occasionally testing it via the HTML5 backend.

Comment: yeah, that's what the official documentation says too. Oh well. I guess that's what it has to be :)

Comment: I added the link. All the best on your exams!

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the project "Run As -> Run Configurations". We should at-least create one configuration for web application. Click on New Configuration and eclipse will automatically fill the information(ie.playn-showcase-html & the class information ). Go ahead and click on Run and you should be able to get you server to run. Hope this helps.